# User not interacting with richtextbox

Tags: c, windows

I create a richtextbox with the following styles

```
WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_NOHIDESEL |  ES_MULTILINE | ES_LEFT | WS_VSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL
```

I want the user to not be able to write in it and the cursor not changing when entering the control.

I tried

```
ES_READONLY
```

property but when the control is clicked it makes a warning noise and the cursor is also changing.

I also tried to disable the control but the background color is changed and the user is
not able to use the scroll any more.

How can I achieve that.

Edit

I forgot to say that I have subclassed the control so I can receive all messages

```
LRESULT CALLBACK RichTextBoxProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwrefData){

    switch(message){
        case WM_PAINT:

            break;
        //(...)

        default:
            return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK RichTextBoxProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwrefData){

    switch(message){
        case WM_PAINT:

            break;
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            SetFocus(mainWindowHandle);

            return 0;
        case WM_SETCURSOR:
            if(LOWORD(lParam) == HTCLIENT ){return 1;}

            break;
        default:
            return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return DefSubclassProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

valter